# Parse String word{xxx} separated by comma

Tags: java, regex, algorithm

I have a String to represent an entity and its properties(also an entity) like :
`String input = "apple{shape,color},orange{taste,price}";`

I want it to split to an array :

```
array[0] = apple{shape,color};
array[1] = orange{taste,price};
```

any words even it has no `{xxx}` can be considered as a entity so do shape and color.

So if I have a `String input = "shape,color"`

```
array[0] = shape
array[1] = color
```

The depth may be more:`String input = "Fruit{apple{shape,color},orange{taste,price}}";`

```
array[0] =  Fruit{apple{shape,color},orange{taste,price}}
```

I tried this but it does not work well,

```
public static String[] split(String input){
    String[] groups = input.split("(?<=\\}),(?=\\w+\\{)");
    return groups;
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output for `Fruit{apple{shape,color},orange{taste,price}}`

Comment: @vks, the same string returns since it it a whole entity

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

Comment: I remember writing a regex solution based on .NET that supports balanced constructs. I do not think you can achieve your goal that easily in Java. You need to create a method parsing the strings the way you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stack to check balance of expression and then assign it as array element. I'll write a pseudo code for you:

```
string s = ""; //initial assignment
stack t;
for i from 0 to exp.length     //exp is your input expression
    if(exp[i] == ',' && stack is empty && s is not null)
        a[k++]=s;
        s = "";
        continue;
    s+=exp[i];
    if(exp[i] == '{')        //I'm checking balance for '{' only, you can extend it further as required
        t.push('{');
    if(exp[i] == '}')
        t.pop();
```